# Is it possible that a specific browser does not support some unicode?

Tags: browser, fonts, unicode

I wrote a HTML5/CSS/JS application which displays some text in [`Droid Sans`](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid%20Sans:400,700) (loaded directly from Google at page load). When developing under Windows, unicode characters are displayed correctly in Chrome.

I started the application with [`epiphany`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Web) in Linux and some unicode characters are not displayed correctly:

- `\u00b0` is fine
- `\ud83d\udd15` is not displayed at all

What could be the reason for that?

- It should not be the font as the same one is used in both Windows and Linux (the remaining of the page looks good).
- This brings me to the browser: could it be the culprit? (I specifically need to use `epiphany` as others I tried do not support some features correctly,  CSS' `flexbox` among others)

In other words: **is it possible that a browser does not support *some* unicode characters, others being displayed correctly (and all of them being fine in another browser on another platform, with the same font)?**

Comment: the browser might have its own ideas about how to substitute the font, or where to load it from. Obviously, if it gets the font from somewhere else, it could have a different 'completeness'

Comment: I modified my question to make it explicit that the font is loaded directly from Google, so it is exactly the same everywhere.

Comment: U+D83D U+DD15 is a surrogate pair, so maybe epiphany doesn't handle those (or doesn't handle them correctly)? Or maybe it doesn't handle non-BMP characters (that surrogate pair is equivalent to U+1F515) correctly (or at all)? I'd ask on the epiphany IRC channel or mailing list.

Comment: @blm: thank you for the suggestion (I have also learned on the occasion that unicode is horribly complicated). The epiphany list suggested to ask on the webkit one - I will update the question if anything useful surfaces.

Comment: Horribly might be overstating it :-), but yes, it does have it's complications. Have you tried another WebKit-based browser? Safari's the most obvious, but there are a [bunch of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#WebKit-based).